# Linq min date max date model querying

Tags: c#, .net, linq, querying

I'm unable to find out on how to get the min date and max date from a dictionary collection.

My model class looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, IList<ErrorModel>> errorList

public class ErrorModel
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do get the min date and max date of the collection.

Hope anyone can help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq's [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) to "flatten" the dictionary values, then use [`Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netcore-3.1) and [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1) methods:

```
var minDate = errorList.SelectMany(s => s.Value).Min(v => v.Date);
var maxDate = errorList.SelectMany(s => s.Value).Max(v => v.Date);
```

However, your `Date` property is defined as a string, you may not get the results you expect.  Updating the definition to `DateTime` will give the correct results using `Min/Max`.

---

If you instead want to get the Min/Max per dictionary `Key`, you could project into an anonymous type:

```
var perKeyMinMax = errorList.Select(d => new { d.Key, 
                                    Min = d.Value.Min(v => v.Date), 
                                    Max = d.Value.Max(v => v.Date) 
                              });
foreach (var item in perKeyMinMax)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {item.Key}, Min: {item.Min}, Max: {item.Max}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will test it once i'm home. And take in your suggestion and change the date property  to datetime